# Wrap li items for each section met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if it's possible to wrap my list items into a ul everytime a li item has class .gsection? So i want to look for the li.gsection tag and them wrap all items until finding the next li.gsection. The ul wrapper should also add two classes where the one is dynamic. li.gsection is always the second classname and my add class is always the third.

I use gravity forms for wordpress so i can't edit the html markup.

Let me know if i have to explain myself more.

**What i have now:**

```html
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Contact Info</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Mail</li>
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Company info</li>
  <li>Company name</li>
  <li>Mail</li>
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Extra Info</li>
  <li>URL</li>
  <li>Notes</li>
</ul>



<ul class="myList">
   <li class="gsectionWrapper contactInfoWrapper">
     <ul>
      <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Contact Info</li>
      <li>Number</li>
      <li>Mail</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="gsectionWrapper companyInfoWrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="gfield gsection companyInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Company info</li> 
      <li>Company name</li>
      <li>Mail</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <ul>
  <li class="gsectionWrapper extraInfoWrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Extra Info</li>
      <li>URL</li>
      <li>Notes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul` cannot have `ul` as child. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: Then i will edit to li.. Does not matter, it's the function my problem is. But thanks for notice

Comment: It needs more: if you just edit to `li`, you also get invalid HTML, as `li` cannot have `li` as child.

Comment: @trincot - I should have it now :) - Do you have any idea for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `wrapAll` function once you have identified a group of `li` elements. To identify those, I would suggest iterating the `.gfield` elements, and grabbing all next (with `nextAll`) until you meet the next `.gfield` (or the end of the list):

```js
var $allFields = $("ul li.gfield");
$allFields.each(function (i) {
    var $group = $(this).nextAll("li").addBack();
    if (i < $allFields.length - 1) {
        $group = $group.slice(0, $group.index($allFields.get(i+1)));
    }
    var className = $(this).attr('class').match(/\b\w+Info\b/) || "";
    $group.wrapAll("<li class='gsectionWrapper " + className + "Wrapper'><ul>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Contact Info</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Mail</li>
  <li class="gfield gsection companyInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Company info</li>
  <li>Company name</li>
  <li>Mail</li>
  <li class="gfield gsection extraInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Extra Info</li>
  <li>URL</li>
  <li>Notes</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool! - Then i only need to dynamicly grabing the third classname from the li: ex. li.companyInfo and then add it to closest li with the wrapper extension. li.companyInfoWrapper.

Comment: Yes, I did not see the logic of that explained in the question. Like for `extraInfoWrapper`: I don't see where you would get it from, except from text content, but that would not be best practice.

Comment: It's also dificult to explain, and i normally use videos to explain. All li tags with the class name .gsection - The third class is always my personal added class. FX. CompanyInfo. So the url group you have in your code should grab the third class from the li tag and then extend it with Wrapper. - Better?

Comment: OK, but that is not what you did in the example for the third section, which has `extraInfoWrapper` instead of `contactInfoWrapper`. Initially all three fields have `contactInfo` as class, but then in your expected output the middle one suddenly has `companyInfo`. So... I am really confused.

Comment: Anyway, I updated the answer with what I think you are up to.

Comment: HELL YEAH!!!! That you so very much!! I starting to understand how that works! Thanks again!.. If you can change the ClassName to this----- var className = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[2];

Answer (score 1):

you could use `$.children()` with `$.each()`

```
const list = $('#myList')
let wrapper;
list.children('li')
  .each(function(){
  const current = $(this)
  if(current.hasClass('gsection')){
    wrapper = $('<ul class="gsectionWrapper contactInfoWrapper"></ul>')
    list.append(wrapper)
  }
   list.detach(current)
   wrapper.append(current)
})
```

```
<ul id='myList' class="myList">
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Contact Info</li>
  <li>Number</li>
  <li>Mail</li>
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Company info</li>
  <li>Company name</li>
  <li>Mail</li>
  <li class="gfield gsection contactInfo otherClassesIsAdded">Extra Info</li>
  <li>URL</li>
  <li>Notes</li>
</ul>
```

this is a working example https://codepen.io/medmor/pen/eYOLrBE

Comment: THANKS! instead of the contactInfoWrapper is manually, is it possible to grab the third classname and then just add the Wrapper to it? - Make sense?

Comment: Yes. if you are sur always classes will be separated with space ```current.attr('class').split(' ')[2]``